# ER model Example SQL

Tags: sql, entity-relationship

I am having trouble with the relationship of this example.

I believe it is recursive but I am not sure.

Car parts are described by partno, price and car type. Car parts can be sub-assemblies as well and can have other parts. One part cannot be apart of more than one sub-assembly but a sub-assembly can contain many other parts. A part need not be a component of any sub-assembly, but a sub-assembly must contain more than one part.

Now I think this is a recursive relationship, but I am not sure any help is appreciated.

Comment: What is it that leads you to think this is recursive?

Comment: It is a super/sub class relationship?

Comment: That sounds hierarchical, not recursive.  Maybe you are just not explaining it well; maybe you aren't clear on what "recursive" means.

Comment: Can sub-assemblies have other sub-assemblies as parts?